# Maps hides when floating right

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-chrome

When google maps iframe floated to right, it shows up and then hides in Google Chrome. It seems its been hidden by javascript when it could not be completely shown, including its margin, although margin does not hide any part of it. Is this really a feature or a bug?

```
<div class=parent>
  <p>
  <iframe class=child allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="250" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" style="border:0" width="300" onload="debugger"></iframe>
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class=parent>
  <p class=hide-seek>
  <iframe class=child allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="250" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d405544.556384143!2d6.6402125!3d61.7258614!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e1!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1502714127200" style="border:0" width="300"></iframe>
  </p>
  </div>
<br>
<input type=button value="Toggle Maps">

.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:red;
  height:280px;
}
.parent p {
  margin:0;
  height:260px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.parent p.hide-seek {
   height:250px;
}    
.parent:nth-child(2)
{
  background-color:blue;
}
iframe {
  float:right;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/zixajetivi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: To answer your question: it is a bug. :)

Comment: So if it incorrectly hides for what situation does it need to hide itself ?